# Can I run distributed transactions in ASP.NET in medium trust?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msdtc, distributed-transactions, medium-trust

I was trying to determine the hardware and software requirements for developing an app and I was wondering if you can run a distributed transaction (through MSDTC) to two different SQL Server instances while maintaining the (web) app in medium trust.

Can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can. Just create an empty ASP.NET application, set the trust level to medium and put a TransactionScope that includes two simultaneous connections to two different databases and two INSERT commands to some tables and see it working. (after you enable the MSDTC service first)